# When equations of the three-body problem reduce to 6 order, why it has no closed-form solution?

Tags: differential-equations, three-body-problem

I know that Sundman had given a series of power expansion solutions to the three-body problem.
But I also find that the three-body problem doesn't have closed-from solution which means it can't be expressed analytically in terms of a finite number of certain "well-known" functions. And this is proved by Poincaré and Bruns:

1. the equations of motion can be written in Hamiltonian form as a set of 18 first order differential equations.
2. besides the 10 integrals (the 6 integrals of the motion of the center of mass, the 3 integrals of angular momentum and the integral of energy), they proved there are no others.
3. together with the “elimination of the time” and the “elimination of the nodes”, the original system of order 18 can be reduced to one of order 6 but it can be reduced no further.

And because of (3), there is no closed form solution to the problem. My question is Why? And is this proved only this method (reduced to 6 order by integrals) doesn't have closed form solution, or all methods don't have?

Comment: This might be a better question for [Mathematics.SE] than here, since it deals with the details of a mathematical proof.

Comment: Since this has now been closed, I would encourage you to try posting this on [Mathematics.SE] and see if you can get an answer over there.  If you do, please link  the post here.  I do think it's an interesting question and would like to see if there's an answer.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I find the 6 equations and asked this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4613741/how-to-prove-these-6-first-odes-have-no-closed-form-solution-about-the-three-b/4613764?noredirect=1#comment9726069_4613764)

Answer (score 1):

You still have equations that you cannot solve analytically, don't you? Tnen, what is meant by *solution* is often ambiguous (e.g., see [this discussion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/587485/247642)) - one could solve equations numerically or postulate a set of special functions defined as solutions of these equations.

Comment: So, it doesn't have a mathematical proof. When they reduced it to 6 order, the equations still can't be tackled. So, they state this doesn't have a closed form solution.

Comment: @Alnseven We cannot obtain solution in terms of [quadratures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrature_(mathematics)). I don't know what the equations in question look like, but it might be a simple mathematical facts that such equations are not solvable (since those that can be solved are known and are few, especially at 6th order.)